# What is the latest version of Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Please can you tell me what is the last Objective-C version for now? and is there any official web-site for this language (like sunmicrosystems for JAVA) for which i can get information about this language?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The "official" Objective-C homepage is [The Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html), as pointed out in the [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/objective-c/info).

Comment: Your answer is not clear. Please sate the difference between Xcode version and Objective-C, its very confusing.

Answer (score 8):

The latest version of objective C is 2.0. I can't find any single website for the language, but [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) contains significant information with external links. [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) is considered the homepage for this language. You may also be interested in [language variants section at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Language_variants). Please note that, though Obj-C 2.0 has garbage collector and iOS use Obj-C 2.0, it does not have GC.

Comment: The 2.0 is largely meaningless.   The language has evolved well beyond the original "2.0" release.

Comment: @bbum, thanks for the info. In all places I have seen 2.0. Is there any official updated version?

Comment: @taskinoor: According to Apples versioning system we are currently at version 4.37.1 (see opensource.apple.com).

Comment: That # isn't really accurate, either, as the compilers delivered in the different SDKs can have different version #s, but otherwise have the same features.  There simply isn't a *language version #* these days.  If anything, the # associated with the SDK is the best.  I.e. The current production version is iOS 4.3 / OS X 10.6.8 and the current NDA'd beta is iOS 5.0 / OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 6):

Objective-C 2.0 was released in 2006, and, as of 2016, there is no 3.0. But that doesn't mean it hasn't changed.

You can find a list of the big Objective-C features supported by Xcode [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/). Sometimes detailed changes can be found in the Xcode release notes [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html). Other changes, like myobject->isa being replaced by object_getClass(myobject), are not advertised very well and you wind up discovering them through compiler warnings.

Five-year-old question, sure, but the answer constantly changes...

Answer (score 2):

It's Objc4 now ! Objc source code here:

https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/objc4/

Comment: is there any training or books available for objective-c 4?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple's open-source web site](http://www.opensource.apple.com/), the version of Objective C 2.0 shipped with the latest version of OS X whose open-source components are available [there](http://www.opensource.apple.com/) (OS X 10.9.4 'Mavericks' as of this writing) is Objective-C 4, revision 551.1.  (Feel free to leave a comment below if you can explain the discrepancy in Objective-C's version numbering between the documentation and the actual source code, would you?)

Comment: I'm confused, is it objective-c 4 out there or is this 4 revision are internal numbering?